# Get SOurce of a drag&drop

Tags: c#, wpf, events, drag-and-drop

I have an `WPF-Datagrid` where I can drop an element. This is a *Textelement* dropped from an *.txt* file (open for example with notepad++). Is there any possibility to get information about the .txt file on my Drop-Event ?

**Edit:**

```
void OnDragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    String text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text, true);
}
```

Here I can get the Text of my drop element, but I found no solution to get the source file, where the drag get started.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Show some research effort!

Comment: I have nothing directly tried, because I have no idea to solve it.The DragEventArgs only presents infos about my droppingcontrol, not where the data comes from.

Comment: Have a look on the documentation then ;) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but i found nothing interesting on msdn.I only found some other questions on some platforms, but noone was answered.You sure, that it's possible to got those source informations?

Answer (score 0):

ok here you go:

You have to do three things to enable drag'n drop in WPF:

1. Tell the element to support drag'n drop
2. Setup a `DragOver` Event
3. Setup a `Drop` Event

ok, let's first look at the XAML:

```
<DataGrid AllowDrop="True"
            DragOver="DataGrid_DragOver"
            Drop="DataGrid_Drop"/>
```

And the event handler code:

```
private void DataGrid_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // check if the element dragged over is one or more files
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        // if so, show a link cursor
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Link;
    }
    else
    {
        // otherwise show a "block" cursor
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    }

    // IMPORTANT: mark the event as "handled by us", to apply the drag effects
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void DataGrid_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if the data dropped is one or more files
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        // get the file pathes from the data object
        string[] filePaths = (e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[]); 

        // do something with the pathes
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

For more information see the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx).

Comment: Thanks 4 helping, but this isn't my problem.I know how to drop files etc., but I'll drop only Text, from a file, so there is no DataFormats.FileDrop, only DataFormat.Text.No i want to find the File, where i have taken text from and dropped into my application

Comment: If you drag drop text from applications like Notepad++ it's not possible, because the application (Notepad++) does only include the actual data into the drag'n drop action. You can get all information included into the action by calling `e.Data.GetFormats()` and then use `e.Data.GetData(currentDataFormat)` to get the information in the current format.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.If someone got an idea how to solve, please write down ;-)

Answer (score 0):

No.

Think of **Drag & Drop** the same way as **Cut & Paste** -- typically only the "data" is being dragged over during the event, and no additional metadata about its source.

One exception to this, is when dragging text from a web page. `DataFormats.Html` will include the SourceURL that the text came from.